# How to get the old data from tables save them into a textbox + add the new value in the textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'll show an example:
Gridview:

```
                     ID Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 
edit,delete,select    1  Chris      22         England
```

If I press edit and edit a value let's say from column 1 : Chris to John
I want to be added in a textbox each time something is changed, a new line like this:

```
ID:1 Column1 value "Chris" was changed to "John" Column2:22 Column3:England
```

So it's like a history of what was changed , so I can print them later . 
SQL Database 2008,c#,asp.net

Thanks, I really need help at this

Comment: I thought about making something but it's stupid and it won't work ..and I have no idea

Comment: Do you want to have them when you click update button?

Answer (score 0):

You can have audit tables for that

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35933/Implementing-Audit-Trail-using-Trigger